# Correct hand for all in?

Tags: all-in

I was playing a low-key local tournament (30 players, NLH) and I was down to about the final 10 (two tables remaining).

I was small blind and had about 5 BB remaining. Most players folded, one called the BB, and it came back to me. I had Q-8 suited and went all-in. Big blind (had about 20 BB stack) called, previous caller folded.

Big blind had 10-10 and won the hand with a pair, nothing exciting came out on the flop/turn/river.

Was it the right hand to go all in on? Or should I have waited for something better?

Comment: There is a lot of information missing here. We need the payout structure and stacksizes.

Comment: We would need more information, such as blind level clock, how fast the table was playing, etc to give a more detailed answer. But imo it's a standard short stack shove.

Answer (score 1):

Low end but according to the charts it is a push.   I think you could go either way.  You pretty much need to get it in before the BB gets back to you and you might not get a better hand.

As commented need more information.

Comment: It was bvb. After sb he is the button.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - could you send me in the direction of some of these types of charts?

Comment: Google short stack push shove

Answer (score 0):

2:1 chips down - this smacks of desperation in the early position. And you're only something like 1% ahead of all other hands pre-flop. Of course the BB is going to call with anything decent. Bad move. But hindsight is a wonderful thing isn't it?

Comment: 1%? 2-4% by my calculation. But the play from the position is the mistake the OP made here as you've mentioned...

Answer (score -1):

Q8s has you slight favourite (in poker cruncher and others) but understand that SB is the worst position to be playing from since you are first to act post flop so a big pair will come over the top.

There are far better hands to shove with from that position but time was against you, so all in all, an understandable play, but a call would have given you a cheaper option than shoving. Fold of course is always the least costly play.

Comment: You cannot check the SB.  5 BB is shove or fold every time.

Comment: What are you talking about - the OP IS the SB?

Comment: Yes, SB needs to call BB at a minimum.